# How to measure food acidity

Tags: measurements, acidity

I am asking about a method or a trick to measure (or guess) how acidic is food.
Please don't suggest any expensive tool; this will be for home usage only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Litmus paper is quite inexpensive. [Edmund Scientific](http://scientificsonline.com/product.asp_Q_pn_E_3021313_A_cmc_E_CROSS_SELL_A_pH+Paper,+Pkg.+of+100) has 100 strips for US$1.95.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this? On supermarkets?

Comment: @mmonem: online, or wherever you might buy chemistry supplies.

Comment: Does it harm the food or I have to use it on a sample of the food?

Comment: @mmonem: My wife, a chemist, doesn't think there should be any problem putting it directly into the food.  They require very small samples, so using it on a sample of a food should work as well.  Dipping a spoon in, and rubbing the paper across the back of the spoon should be fine.  The only problem I could see is if you food has a deep color (tomato sauce, blackberries, etc).  It might be hard to tell the color of the strip through the food coloring.

Comment: @mmonem: If you're in the US, you can order them at the link I gave. Otherwise just search in Google Shopping for litmus paper. [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Homemade-pH-Paper-Test-Strips) is a page which gives instructions more making pH test paper of various types yourself.

Comment: It's unfortunate that even Edmund Scientific describes that as "litmus paper" - litmus is really a specific pH indicator, that classic red/blue acid/base test that you might've used in your high school chemistry class.

Answer (score 0):

Some less precise methods using common ingredients:

Anthocyanin-containing foods (red cabbage, blueberries...) tend to turn blue in an alkaline, red in an acidic environment. Turmeric goes more lemon-yellow in acidic, more orange in very alkaline environments.

Baking soda can indicate strong acidity, it will activate and foam.

If there are green vegetables in a dish, their cooked colour gives you a hint about the cooking liquid (effect is not instant!)- if their color tends to go in the direction of olive drab, you are quite acidic; if they are unnaturally green your cooking liquid is rather alkaline.

Also, browning behaviour, especially of protein rich foods, gives you a hint - if it is hard to brown, your marinade might be just too acidic.